# Correct format to input date with time of the day

Tags: c#, datetime, time

I want to be able to calculate the time in hours and minutes elapsed between, say, 12:35pm  02/13/2016 to 1:45pm 02/14/2016, but can't figure out the correct format to input it.
EDIT: Should add that the span between the times will be stored in an arraylist, one span per customer.

Comment: What format are the date times in? Are they strings, or already instances of `DateTime`?

Comment: Difference betweeen two datetimes produces a TimeSpan that contains all the properties you need. Just create two datetimes, subtract and look at the resulting TimeSpan

Comment: My question is how to create a datetime that includes time of day...by user input.

Comment: What does the user input look like? String, DatePicker? Are you by any chance looking for `DateTime.Parse`?

Comment: Are you really using an `ArrayList`? They're so 2002.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need something like this:

```
var dateA = new DateTime(2016,2,13,12,35,0);
var dateB = new DateTime(2016,2,14,1,45,0);

var timespan = dateB - dateA;
var hours = timespan.Hours;
bar minutes = timespan.Minutes;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would go about it:

```
Func<string, DateTime?> tryParse = t =>
{
    DateTime output;
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(
        t,
        new [] { "h:mmtt MM/dd/yyyy" },
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
        System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal,
        out output))
    {
        return output;
    }
    return null;
};

var dt1 = tryParse("12:35pm 02/13/2016");
var dt2 = tryParse("1:45pm 02/14/2016");

TimeSpan? ts = null;
if (dt1.HasValue && dt2.HasValue)
{
    ts = dt2.Value.Subtract(dt1.Value);
}

if (ts.HasValue)
{
    Console.WriteLine(
        String.Format(
            "{0} hours & {1} minutes",
            ts.Value.Hours,
            ts.Value.Minutes));
}
```